# nodejs - pkg Error! Not more than one entry file/directory is expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, vercel

I have a simple cli node script that I want to pack using `pkg`.
I've tried with the following command

```js
host:~ dev$ pkg /Users/dev/Desktop/myscript/ --target node14-macos-x64 node14-linux-x64 node14-win-x64
```

unfortunately I will get this error in terminal

```
> pkg@4.4.9
> Error! Not more than one entry file/directory is expected
```

If I try to remove the target instead, I will get this other error in terminal

```
> pkg@4.4.9
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
  node15-linux-x64, node15-macos-x64, node15-win-x64
> Error! No available node version satisfies 'node15'
```

In my system I'm running node v15.4.0 so I can't understand what's wrong.

My project package.json file looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "myscript",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "bin": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "commander": "^7.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "facebook-chat-api": "^1.8.0",
    "forever-monitor": "^3.0.3",
    "node-notifier": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

How I can pack my app and fix these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're missing an `s` : use `--targets` instead of `--target`

> pkg can generate executables for several target machines at a time. You can specify a comma-separated list of targets via --targets

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

Comment: Also with the typo fixed I continue to get this error `> pkg@4.4.9
> Error! Not more than one entry file/directory is expected` . My main file is index.js and will spawn a child process that execute the main script. I don't know if this is the problem