# How to create a executable file using PKG (going wrong because of Node 20)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to transform this simple code into a executable, I didn't create any .json file, just the .js file.

It's my first time working with .JS, every time I ran `pkg script.js` it returns the error "Error! No available node version satisfies 'node20'".

Here's my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const cliProgress = require('cli-progress');

const { DEFAULT_INTERCEPT_RESOLUTION_PRIORITY, Mouse } = require('puppeteer');
const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker');
const progressBar = new cliProgress.SingleBar({}, cliProgress.Presets.shades_classic);
const totalItens = 110;
puppeteer.use(
  AdblockerPlugin({
    // Optionally enable Cooperative Mode for several request interceptors
    interceptResolutionPriority: DEFAULT_INTERCEPT_RESOLUTION_PRIORITY
  })
);


function timeToMilliseconds(time) {
    const [minutes, seconds] = time.split(':').map(Number);
    const minutesInMilliseconds = minutes * 60 * 1000;
    const secondsInMilliseconds = seconds * 1000;
    const totalMilliseconds = minutesInMilliseconds + secondsInMilliseconds;
    return totalMilliseconds;
  }
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'new'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.justwatch.com/br/filme/besouro-azul');
    let title = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.getElementsByClassName("title-block")[0].textContent
    });
    console.log("TITULO: ", title)
    await page.click('[class="youtube-player__play-button youtube-player__play-button--backdrop"', 'left');
    progressBar.start(totalItens, 0)
    for (let i = 0; i <= totalItens; i++){
        progressBar.update(i)
        await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
        setInterval(() => {
        }, 1000);
    }
    title = title.split(' ')
    const filename = title[0] + '.png'
    await page.screenshot({path: filename});

    await browser.close();
    progressBar.stop();
})();
```

I was expecting to create a EXE file so I can share my code with friends.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What Node version(s) do you have installed?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and the v20.10.0 version of Node

Comment: The error suggests to me that `node20` needs to be registered as a command on your system. Does that work at the Windows command line?

Comment: no, it isnt a command at the cmd

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76332536/how-to-package-node-js-app-with-pkg-library-when-using-specific-node-js-versio). See you can use the `target` option as noted in that question.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076767/nodejs-pkg-error-not-more-than-one-entry-file-directory-is-expected).